# What should I do to ensure Spring is thread safe?

Tags: spring, hibernate

May I know by configuring the data source in Spring like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/dev"/>
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="dataSource"/>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

And configuring my BOC and DAO object in Spring like this:

```
<bean id="Dao" class="com.dao.impl.DaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="Bo" class="com.bo.impl.BoImpl">
  <property name="theDao">
    <ref local="Dao"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Currently I am testing it with 3 users, 1 successfully insert data into DB, 1 is hung, and 1 is missing in action, meaning there is no response, no log was capture in Websphere Application Server. With 3 users concurrently using the app has failed the test case, may I know how could I ensure all these are thread safe when come to a situation when there are 1000 users using the app concurrently?

---

**UPDATE**

In response to @Adrian Shum query:

Regarding the BO thing, I'm not sure what pattern is this. But I'm BOC is stand for Business Object Controller, the purpose of having this unit class is to separate the business logic from DAO object. Eventually this will end up the XHTML/JSP is the front-end, BO is the business controller, and DAO is concern about hibernate and query construction.

In order to retrieve the session factory, every DAO object must extends the HibernateDaoSupport, this is how Spring-Hibernate Integration work according to this tutorial. Here is some code snippet:

```
class DAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IDao {

  public void save( Pojo pojo ) {
    getHibernateTemplate().save(pojo);
  }

  public void update( Pojo pojo ) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(pojo);
  }

  public void delete( Pojo pojo ) {
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(pojo);
  }
}
```

I know that Spring object are singleton by default. Does this means each thread will have only ONE object or the whole JVM instance will have only ONE object? What if I declare those BO and DAO object as session scope like this:

```
<bean id="Dao" class="com.dao.impl.DaoImpl" scope="session">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="Bo" class="com.bo.impl.BoImpl" scope="session">
  <property name="theDao">
    <ref local="Dao"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Regarding the data update or retrieval, this could happen as the 3 users that we are testing on is actaully targeting on the same record. There might be a lock as I notice that there is a function doing this code:

```
Query queryA = session.createQuery("Delete From TableA where fieldA = :theID");
queryA.setParameter("theID", "XX");
queryA.executeUpdate();

Query queryB = session.createQuery("Delete From TableB where fieldB = :theID");
queryB.setParameter("theID", "YY");
queryB.executeUpdate();

// update tableB object
session.save(tableBObj);

// update each tableA object
for(TableAObj obj : TableAObjList) {                
  session.save(obj);
  session.flush();
  session.evict(obj);
}
```

The TableA(slave) and TableB(master) has relationship in each other. I know there is a database design between TableA and TableB but this is beyond of this question. I'm just curious whether this function could cause the concurrent issue even though I made this class as singleton?

Comment: You could try prayer and fasting

Comment: I think, you should use a connection pooling mechanism like c3p0 and transaction manager.

Comment: Can you publish the **theDao** method that saves the entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the problem resolved. It is due to the DB2 failed to handle concurrency issues by adding a new column into the table, and make it as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

From your problem, it is obviously that the thread-safeness is nothing to do with Spring.

There can be a lot of place that can go wrong, for example: (I don't really know what your BO means, as it seems not a well know pattern.  I assume your "user" will invoke method in BO and BO will invoke DAO to do the data retrieval job)

How are you using the session factory? I wish you are not getting one session and keep on using that.  It will be great to show some code snippet on how you use it.

If your BO is a singleton, does it keep any state for individual "user session"?  Is any shared object used in the processing not thread-safe?

for issue related to DAO which is data retrieval and update, have you did your work to avoid dead lock? for example, function A will update table X and then table Y, while function B update Y then X.  Have you done your work to make sure that, for 2 users updating the same record, the latter update won't silently overwrite the former one (in case the update is not idempotent).

There can be tons of reason causing your problem, but I believe 99.999% of them have nothing to do with Spring (or Hibernate).